# Comparing strings in two different files and returning common ones

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Using a ksh script to try and compare two files that I get.  I have tried using comm, diff, and grep but can't get the results I want.  I can show below what I am trying to do.

one.txt

```
name1
name2
```

two.txt

```
name1|email1
name2|email2
name3|email3
```

I have tried using grep -f but I get the illegal option on my machine so I'm looking for something different.  Is there anyway I can look in the file one and see those strings, then look in file two and see matching strings and pull out the second value from two.txt so it looks like this?

three.txt

```
email1
email2
```

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a job for [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html).  If the files are already sorted (as in the example data):

```
join -t '|' -o 2.2 one.txt two.txt
```

If the files are not already sorted and you have Bash or Korn shell with [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
join -t '|' -o 2.2 <(sort one.txt) <(sort two.txt)
```

If you don't have Bash or Korn shell with process substitution:

```
tmp=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/j.XXXXXX)
trap "rm -f $tmp.?; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

sort one.txt > $tmp.1
sort two.txt > $tmp.2
join -t '|' -o 2.2 $tmp.1 $tmp.2

rm -f $tmp.?
trap 0
```

(You could use one temporary file, but this is symmetric which makes it clearer what's going on.)

Answer (score 1):

```
for entry in $(cat one.txt)
do 
    grep $entry two.txt| awk -F"|" '{print $NF}' 
done > three.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ cat one.txt
name1
name2
$ cat two.txt
name1|email1
name2|email2
name3|email3
$ cat filter.ksh
#! /usr/bin/ksh
for LINE in $(cat one.txt); do
  sed -n "s/$LINE|//p" two.txt
done
$ ./filter.ksh
email1
email2
```